# Unable to use paths with spaces in FFMPEG, Android

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, android

I'm using ffmpeg command line in Android. When I use the command `ffmpeg -i /sdcard/d 1.jpg`, it says `/sdcard/d: No such file or directory`.

I tried `/sdcard/d\ 1.jpg` which showed error as `/sdcard/d\: No such file or directory`

`/sdcard/d'\' 1.jpg` shows error `/sdcard/d': No such file or directory`

`/sdcard/d' '1.jpg` shows error `/sdcard/d': No such file or directory`

`'/sdcard/d 1.jpg'` shows error `'/sdcard/d: No such file or directory`

However it works for `/sdcard/d.jpg` and shows the file information.
I also have the file in the path, checked it many times.

What am I doing wrong here? How should I correct it so I can use input and output paths with spaces?

Comment: Have you tried with `"/sdcard/d 1.jpg"`?

Comment: I just tried it now. It shows the same error as `"/sdcard/d: No such file or directory` It works for /sdcard/d.jpg though.

Comment: @Rahul the solution in the below link works, please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253828/how-to-make-ffmpeg-cmd-run-if-there-is-space-in-director-path-or-file-name